# How do I return "Yes" if all words in the sentence are lowercase?

Tags: python

I can currently have my code return "Yes" for each character, but I'm not sure how to make the code return just **ONE Yes** at the end of the code, if every word in the sentence was lowercase. Here's what I have

```
sentence = "hello thEre is this aLL lowercase"
sent = sentence.split(" ")
lower = False
for wd in sent:
    for ch in wd:
        if ch.islower():
            print("Yes")
            lower = True
        if not ch.islower():
            print("No")
            lower = False
```

I know I cannot have print("Yes") in the loop because it will print everytime, but I don't know how to do it any other way. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Unless this is for educational purposes, you don't need to check every character separately. `"hello thEre is this aLL lowercase".islower()` returns `False`, `"this is all low".islower()` returns `True`.

Comment: Why don't you drop the loop and check the whole string instead: `if sentence.islower():`?

Comment: Hint you don't need to check if lower, only if not lower and you don't have to continue to check the entire string.

Comment: "I can currently have my code return "Yes"" Just to clarify terminology, you **print** "Yes", but you don't return it. These are two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to approach the solution.

I’m intentionally not providing any explanation, because it will help your learning to research the concepts on your own.  Look into:

- List comprehension
- The `all()` function
- Boolean tests

#### Sample code:

```
s = ‘lower case statement’

result = all([i.islower() for i in s.split()])

print('Yes' if result else 'No')
>>> ‘Yes’
```

I recommend taking each part of the short code apart to discover how it’s working.

#### Simplified:

Personally, I don’t mind sharing this in an educational setting, because part of learning to write Python (and code in general) is learning to write it **efficiently**.  That said, here’s a simplified solution:

```
print('Yes' if s.islower() else 'No')
>>> ‘Yes’
```

Comment: I think all() accepts a generator, so you don't need the list.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it. It makes 100% sense too. I thought the islower() only checks a character. I didn't know it could do an entire sentence. Once again, thank you for the help.

Comment: @Gavin - My pleasure mate.

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about it being all lowercase then the first time you find a capital letter you should break out of the loop. Then only print yes if lower is true outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is an exercise, so I won't give any code.

You need to have a variable "any non-lowercase word found" that is set to false before the loop and set to true if a word is found that is not lowercase. If the variable is still false after the loop you can print "yes", otherwise not.

Maybe if you have written the code to implement this you will find that it can be optimized.

Comment: I appreciate the help. This helps me understand the set to false before the loop idea. I have never really understood that before. So basically.. if something trips that flag, we print "no". But it it remains false the whole time, we can print "yes"!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isLower()`, just remember to remove spaces

```
def checkLower(string):
    string = string.replace(" ","")
    print(string)
    for i in string:
        if i.islower() == False:
            return "no"
    return "yes"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this way using `.islower()` because The [islower()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/islower.html) methods return **True** if all characters in the string are lowercase, Otherwise, It returns **False**.

```
sentence = "hello thEre is this aLL lowercase"
if(sentence.isLower()):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = "hello there this is all lowercase"
sent = sentence.split(" ")
lower = True
for wd in sent:
    for ch in wd:
        if not ch.islower():
            lower = False
if lower:
   print("Yes")
if not lower:
   print("No")
```

I don't have much idea about python and how it works but here is the logic i added to the code provided.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are printing "Yes" every time you find a lowercase word.

```
def isAllLower(sentence):
    sent = sentence.split(" ")
    lower = False
    for wd in sent:
        for ch in wd:
            if ch.islower():
                lower = True
            if not ch.islower():
                lower = False
    if lower == True:
        print("Yes")
    elif lower == False:
        print("No")

isAllLower("hello thEre is this aLL lowercase")
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest by far way is to compare the lowered by default sentence using the lower() function, with the initial function!

```
def SentenceisLower(sentence):
    sentencelower = sentence.lower()
    if (sentence == sentencelower):
        print("Yes!")
```

Where there is no reply in any other outcome!